# What's the secure way to store consumer key in a command line app?

Tags: python, security, command-line, pypi

I'm building a command-line app that works with Python. It helps people to find potentially fake users on Twitter and mute or block them to have a better Twitter timeline, and To do the authorization, I'm using tweepy.

The problem is, to [create an authorization URL](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-1a-authentication) (to redirect users so they can grant access to their Twitter account) tweepy needs to have my application's consumer_key and consumer_secret:

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
```

I wonder what's the best practice and secure way to store these keys in the app (that's a Python package, published in pypi and github), so everyone will be able to use the app, and also no one will misuse the keys. I'd appreciate your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) module to store it:

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("mycoolapp", "key", consumer_key)
consumer_key = keyring.get_password("mycoolapp", "key")
```

It'll make use of the system keyring service (Keychain / KWallet / Windows Credential Locker etc). It's probably better than my normal approach of storing conf files in the user's home dir.

Comment: Seems like an interesting tool, but still I need to give the raw password to the user this way, right?

Comment: Yes, you would. Sorry, I misunderstood. So you're wanting your users to access the Twitter API using your own API key, but for them to not know it? You could write a proxy web app to make the requests of the Twitter API and have your command line app connect to endpoints on your proxy app. They don't need to know about the internals that make the proxy work that way (your consumer key and consumer secret).

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If users want to authorize on twitter, they need to request for an app API from twitter. But it's a long process, and I want to make it easy for them to authorize with the app's own consumer key.

Comment: If you're giving them the key to use you can't stop them using that key how they like. You need an extra layer of indirection - host your own proxy app to talk to Twitter, and have your command-line app talk to your proxy. Your users don't need to know your key that way.

Answer (score 0):

To briefly summarize [this question and answer](http://%20https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246484/securing-api-keys-for-a-twitter-account-for-a-program-to-be-run-on-other-pcs), it is nearly impossible to do this without using more complex methods such as Intel SGX or homomorphic encryption, both of which are not very practical options, and even using these will not guarantee the safety of your keys.

If you're storing keys on the end user's machine, there are countless ways that they can be intercepted (e.g. by the user just intercepting web requests to the API as the program works). If they're on a non-trusted machine you don't have control over, **your keys are not safe**.

You'll be better off setting up a node that *you have control over* which your users can then connect to.

Comment: By "node", you mean something like an API that works on my own server?

Comment: Yes, your account keys are only safe if *you* are the one who is in full control of them on your own machine.